# Reducing the font size of text of days and the week in MUI StaticDatePicker Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { StaticDatePicker} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker';

const DateCalander = () => {

    return (
            <Box sx={{
                bgcolor: 'white', 
                borderRadius: 3,
                }}>      
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                    <StaticDatePicker  sx={{
                            width: '500px', 
                            height: '300px',
                            ".StaticDatePicker-calendarContainer .DayPicker-Day": { 
                                fontSize: "10px"  
                            },
                            ".DayPicker-Day": {
                                fontSize: "10px", // adjust the font size as desired
                            },
                        }}       
                        />
                </LocalizationProvider>   
            </Box>
       
    );
};

export default DateCalander;
```

I tried several things other than the one I have done above but the font size doesn't change. Please kelp. :)

I basically want to reduce the fontsize of all the text in the `<StaticDatePicker/>` component so it can adjust to the design of the component I am making.

Comment: [Documentation for Customisation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/), you would be after [Overriding styles with class names](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names). With a really quick look, it appears you are missing some ampersands i.e.  `".StaticDatePicker-calendarContainer .DayPicker-Day"` should be `"& .StaticDatePicker-calendarContainer .DayPicker-Day"`

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { StaticDatePicker} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker';

const DateCalander = () => {
    return (    
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
             <StaticDatePicker
                 sx={{
                     "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {  fontSize: "10px" }     // <=====
                 }}       
             />
        </LocalizationProvider> 
    );
};

export default DateCalander;
```